# Troubleshooting a bash script using chroot. Are there differences between 20.04 and 22.04?

Tags: apt, chroot

I am using a bash script that does things under a chroot. It was working well a long time ago like this :

```
copy stuff here and there then

  sudo chroot . su - root -c "\
set -o xtrace ; \
cd /tmp/wheresthestuff ; \
. $ScriptName ; \
ModifyThisCHROOT ; \
exit 0 ; \
"
```

Up to 22.04 it seems to do the job correctly.
But from Ubuntu 22.04 the apt-get install seems to stall everything.
An strace from this specific blocking command show this :

```
sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive strace apt-get \
        --assume-yes \
        --reinstall \
        --force-yes \
        --fix-broken \
        --option Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew \
        install \
        --no-install-recommends \
        $package 
...
pselect6(34, [0 31 33], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=50000000}, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [33], left {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49998940})
wait4(199664, 0x7ffe6b270bd0, WNOHANG, NULL) = 0
pselect6(34, [0 31 33], NULL, NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=50000000}, {sigmask=[], sigsetsize=8}) = 1 (in [33], left {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=49998520})
wait4(199664, [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], WNOHANG, NULL) = 199664
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=199664, si_uid=0, si_status=0, si_utime=1, si_stime=0} ---
close(33)                               = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f074fe78520}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[QUIT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f074fe78520}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f074fe78520}, {sa_handler=0x7f07503ab4d0, sa_mask=[INT], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f074fe78520}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[HUP], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f074fe78520}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[HUP], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f074fe78520}, 8) = 0
close(32)                               = 0
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_CONTINUE or TCSETSF, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = ? ERESTARTSYS (To be restarted if SA_RESTART is set)
--- SIGTTOU {si_signo=SIGTTOU, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---
--- stopped by SIGTTOU ---
```

I am not able to sort it out. Any advice?

Comment: Not exactly sure why apt-get would stall inside a chroot, but there's lots of reasons why it would fail. I usually bind-mount /dev, /dev/pts, /sys, and /proc from my system into a chroot before actually chrooting. Also, you need to remember to copy /etc/resolv.conf from the host into the chroot if you want apt-get to have Internet access.

Comment: That's my point... Why not just failing with an error we could then handle... Everything that needs to be done for the apt-get to work under Ubuntu <22.04 is. And apt-get run correctly for <22.04. So yes, any network layer configuration is working, and any necessary mount has been done. Execpt if something new has to be done from 22.04.

Comment: As a workaround this new apt-get bug, we removed ```2>&1 | tee /tmp/build.log``` from our shell command line. Please Canonical, could you please investigate this ?

Comment: You'll probably get a much better response if you make an account on https://launchpad.net/ and file a bug report there.

Comment: Yep, yep, yep ... Done.

Comment: Still no news nor progress on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1980881